# Django: Count and display amount of items in a person order

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to display a count of how many products are in a persons order. How do I go about doing that? I want to display the total item count in a order_detail.html page.

Below is my code for reference.

models.py:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, default=increment_order_id, null=True, blank=True, 
    editable=False)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    route = models.ForeignKey(Route, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, blank=True)
    delivery_date = models.DateField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    discount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)


class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                          related_name='items', null=True)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    # Item
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, 
    related_name='order_items')
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1, null=False)
```

views.py:

```
@method_decorator(login_required(login_url='account_login'), name='dispatch')
class OrderListView(ListFilteredMixin, ListView):
    model = Order
    template_name = 'orders/order/list.html'
    filter_set = OrderFilter
    queryset = Order.objects.all()
 

@login_required(login_url='account_login')
def order_detail(request, order_id):
    order = get_object_or_404(Order, order_id=order_id)
    order_item = OrderItem.objects.filter(order=order)

    context = {
        'order': order,
        'order_item': order_item
         }
    return render(request, 'orders/order/detail.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1):

Update your code to this:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, default=increment_order_id, null=True, blank=True, 
    editable=False)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    route = models.ForeignKey(Route, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, blank=True)
    delivery_date = models.DateField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    discount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
    
    def count_items(self):
        return self.items.count()
```

then call in html as `{{ order.count_items }}`

Comment: This works, but does not include the quantity of each item. So there is 4x "Product 1" in the order. I want the count to show "4" instead of "1".